# Не запускаетс Django Apache2

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache2, wsgi

Не запускается проект на джанго. Уже прорыл весь гугл но решение на проблему найти не смог. Вот логи:

```
 [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690022 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156] mod_wsgi (pid=27628): Target WSGI script '/home/gala/gala/gala/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690049 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156] mod_wsgi (pid=27628): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/gala/gala/gala/wsgi.py'.
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690072 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690097 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156]   File "/home/gala/gala/gala/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690133 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690143 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156]   File "/home/gala/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690158 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156]     from django.utils.version import get_version
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690166 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156]   File "/home/gala/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 71, in <module>
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690180 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156]     @functools.lru_cache()
    [Sat Oct 03 07:38:46.690202 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 27628] [remote 163.172.145.116:3156] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

Comment: во-первых лучше юзать NGinx

Comment: @Данил да понимаю. Но нужно запустить на апач

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609614/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-lru-cache у человека на англоязычном SO было что-то похожее, может поможет?

Comment: @mrEvgenX читал. Не помогло